# Create dynamic select get value for column name - in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, dynamic-sql

Please help me create a select SQL statement with the results column name get from the column values in origin table (tablename is `Device_Part`):

[image]

User can input many `DeviceCode` which have many dynamic `PartTypeName`, the PartTypeName value is the `PartInfo`.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for dynamic MS SQL pivot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Thanks you very much, i try it but it may hard to understand for me, and maybe it have constant value, when my values is dynamic

Comment: If I write your code for you I'll charge you my normal hourly rate!  But I'll help you for free.  Have a go.  Make some mistakes.  Learn some stuff on the way.  Then come back with what you tried, and tell us in what way it does not work.  Remember to include error messages and sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will try it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help:

```
CREATE Table Device (
DeviceCode NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PartTypeName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PartInfo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

Insert Into Device
Values('VT.SX-01','CPU','Pentium G6650'),
('VT.SX-01','Motherboard','H81M -  S2PV'),
('VT.SX-01','RAM','DDR# 4GB - bus 1866 - Nano'),
('VT.SX-01','PartType Name 01','PartInfo 01')

--QUERY
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ColumnNamesInPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Get distinct values of PIVOT Column 
SELECT   @ColumnNamesInPivot = ISNULL(@ColumnNamesInPivot + ',', '')
        + QUOTENAME([PartTypeName])
FROM    ( SELECT    DISTINCT
                    [PartTypeName]
          FROM      Device
        ) AS P



SELECT  @DynamicPivotQuery = N'Select DeviceCode,'
        + @ColumnNamesInPivot + ' 
            FROM    ( SELECT * 
          FROM      Device
        ) AS SourceTable PIVOT( MAX(PartInfo) FOR [PartTypeName] IN ('
        + @ColumnNamesInPivot + ') ) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

And the result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your work hard answer ! I run the first select success: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5560/30407745360_5dc7583532_o_d.jpg , but the second is failed: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5532/30707958185_4e3460c27e_o_d.jpg . Could you please help me try it, thanks you so much!

Comment: and error if i run 2 select together: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5343/30708083475_535c6c2196_o_d.jpg . Could you please help me try it, thanks you so much!

Comment: I have edited the query... in order to get the desired out put, you need to select the query part from declaration of variables upto the end

Comment: Hien Nguyen, did you get what you wanted?

Comment: You are my master, the result is exactly my expected, thousand like for you, Thanks you very much for your enthusiastically help! https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5702/30090888554_d947cf4179_o_d.jpg . I would like to learn this technical SQL, could you please help me the technical name so i can find this on google. Thanks you!

Comment: You are welcome! The following links may help you get the general idea about SQL PIVOT and dynamic sql queries: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx,http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127147/discussion-between-yared-and-hien-nguyen).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

;WITH _CTE(_DeviceCode,_PartTypeName,_PartInfo,_Id)
AS
(
 SELECT DeviceCode,PartTypeName,PartInfo ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY      PartTypeName ORDER BY Id) FROM Your_tablename
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT _DeviceCode,_PartTypeName,_PartInfo
FROM _CTE
)C
PIVOT
(
 MAX(_PartInfo) FOR _PartTypeName IN ([CPU],[MotherBoard],[RAM],[PartTypeName])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer, but the PartTypeName is dynamic, not only are [CPU],[MotherBoard],[RAM] , we can input more as Power, Monitor, Keyboard......